# Why is my php script not returning any variables?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've been trying for a while to add a 'load more' button to a php script.

I've got a rather complicated MYSQL query here that does work but I am now trying to use with prepared statements and just output two variables.

Whilst the script *does* return the expected number of results it's not actually echoing out any variables. I suspect the problem lies in the foreach loops... In the console response I can see this:

```
<li>-</li><li>-</li><li>-</li>
```

The script

```
//get current starting point of records
$position = (($page_number-1) * $item_per_page);

//fetch records 
$results = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT up.id,up.file,up.title,p.user_name,p.user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(cp.user_id,'~',cp.user_name) SEPARATOR '|') AS tagGroup
FROM tbl_uploads up
LEFT JOIN tbl_users p ON up.user_id = p.user_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_collab c ON up.file = c.file
LEFT JOIN tbl_users cp ON cp.user_id = c.collab_userid
GROUP BY up.file ORDER BY up.id LIMIT ?, ?");

//bind parameters for markers
$results->bind_param("dd", $position, $item_per_page); 
$results->execute(); //Execute prepared Query
$results->bind_result($title, $file); //bind variables to prepared statement

//output results from database

while($row = $results->fetch()){ //fetch values

$titles =  explode (",", $row['title']);
$files = explode (",", $row['file']);

foreach($titles as $title) {
foreach($files as $file) {
    echo '<li>'.$title.'-'.$file.'</li>';   
}
}
}
```

Here's an example of the out put from phpadmin.
[image]

Comment: what does `var_dump($titles, $files);` output?

Comment: Could you please post the output of var_dump($row)?

Comment: var_dump($row) gives bool(true) bool(true) bool(true) bool(true) bool(true) bool(true).

Comment: var_dump($titles, $files); gives array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" }

Comment: What about the values of `$title` and `$file`?

Comment: All of your columns are empty strings? Do you get results if you run this query elsewhere, like in workbench etc..?

Comment: in answer to Jon Stirling's question I get string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) ""

Comment: Then sounds like your data is dodgy to me.

Comment: @JonStirling agreed, Id like to see  the results of running the raw query

Comment: I don't know about work bench but if I run the query in php admin say I get results and which I can echo straight out. Using prepared statements is causing me the problems (the script I am using requires me to bind page number and position to the results).

Comment: can you show an image of the results you get and the query itself in phpmyadmin? It would help to see the actual data

Comment: Why do you select 6 columns but only bind 2?

Comment: Well it's a 'load more' script I got off the web and it seems I need to bind $page number and $items_per_page to the results to enable the load more to work. I'll admit it's really pushing my limited understanding.

Comment: And wont this bind `up.id` to `$title`, that doesnt seem like what you want

Comment: FYI this works..."SELECT file
FROM tbl_uploads LIMIT ?, ?" and then while($results->fetch()){ 
 echo '<li>'.$file.'</li>';    I added in the the while($row=results->fetch())....which may have caused the issue.

Comment: Can you give us a link to the documentation for the "load more" script that tells you you need to do this?

Comment: https://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/loading-more-results-from-database

Comment: Ok, i see the issue, and are these the two values you want to print out? up.file,up.title

Comment: Also, it would really help to know what a value stored in $row['title'] looks like. I assume it hold a coma separated list?

Comment: How might I show that to you?

Comment: You could just copy and paste the value from the `title` field of one of your results in phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding how [`bind_result()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) works.

> When mysqli_stmt_fetch() is called to fetch data, the MySQL client/server protocol places the data for the bound columns into the specified variables var1, ....

This means that the columns listed in your select statement get mapped to the variables listed in your call to `bind_result()`

For example, if you had `SELECT first_name, last_name FROM names` and you called:

`$results->bind_result($first, $last);`

When you loop over the results, for each row, the value from `first_name` will be available via the variable `$first` and the value from `last_name` will be available via `$last`

That means you could do:

```
while($results->fetch()){ //fetch values
    echo 'Hi '.$first.' '.$last;
}
```

**Try your code like this:**

```
        //fetch records
        // change your select to only select the columns you need and the order needs to be the same as bind_result below
        $results = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT up.file,up.title
                                     FROM tbl_uploads up
                                     LEFT JOIN tbl_users p ON up.user_id = p.user_id
                                     LEFT JOIN tbl_collab c ON up.file = c.file
                                     LEFT JOIN tbl_users cp ON cp.user_id = c.collab_userid
                                     GROUP BY up.file ORDER BY up.id LIMIT ?, ?");




        //bind parameters for markers
        $results->bind_param("dd", $position, $item_per_page);
        $results->execute(); //Execute prepared Query
        $results->bind_result($title, $file); //bind variables to prepared statement
        // this binds the selected columns to the variable names given for use below
        // $title below is equivalent to $result['title] inside a for loop 



        while($results->fetch()){ //fetch values 
            echo '<li>'.$title.'-'.$file.'</li>';
        }
```

Comment: Yes! That works great. Thank you very much for all you help and patience.